# Get difference of rows between a two queries that have and doesn't have DISTINCT keyword - TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this sort of query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

k.Key1, k.Key2, 
p.Key3, p.Key4, 
vp.Key5 

FROM [MY_DB].[dbo].[MY_TABLE_1] AS vp

INNER JOIN MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE_2 AS k 
ON vp.Code1 = k.Key1 AND vp.Code2 = k.Key3

INNER JOIN MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE_3 AS p 
ON p.Key3 = vp.Code3 

WHERE vp.Year = 2018
```

I want to find the rows that differ when I run this query with DISTINCT and without it. When without DISTINCT I get, 1875 results and with DISTINCT I get 1656 which turns out there are 219 in the difference.

I am not very skilled with T-SQL.

Can somebody give me some ideas how to get the results in the difference?

Note: I already used GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY k.Key1, k.Key2, k.Key3
```

but I got only 185 results which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `group by`.  The reason you are getting different counts is because the columns you are selecting are duplicates.

So, `group by` and `count(*)`.  You can get the number of duplicates as well:

```
SELECT k.Key1, k.Key2, p.Key3, p.Key4, vp.Key5, count(*) as num_duplicates
FROM MY_DB.[dbo].[MY_TABLE_1] vp INNER JOIN
     MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE_2 k 
     ON vp.Code1 = k.Key1 AND vp.Code2 = k.Key3 INNER JOIN
     MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE_3 p 
     ON p.Key3 = vp.Code3 
WHERE vp.Year = 2018
GROUP BY k.Key1, k.Key2, p.Key3, p.Key4, vp.Key5
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If you want to select more columns to get more information about the duplicates, you can use a window function instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT k.Key1, k.Key2, p.Key3, p.Key4, vp.Key5, . . .,
             count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY k.Key1, k.Key2, p.Key3, p.Key4, vp.Key5) as num_duplicates
      FROM MY_DB.[dbo].[MY_TABLE_1] vp INNER JOIN
           MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE_2 k 
           ON vp.Code1 = k.Key1 AND vp.Code2 = k.Key3 INNER JOIN
           MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE_3 p 
           ON p.Key3 = vp.Code3 
      WHERE vp.Year = 2018
     ) x
WHERE num_duplicates > 1;
```

The `. . .` is for extra columns that might help you diagnose your unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

Then logically, you're trying to find the rows which are duplicates. So a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` instead of `DISTINCT` should tell you:

```
SELECT

k.Key1, k.Key2, 
p.Key3, p.Key4, 
vp.Key5 

FROM [MY_DB].[dbo].[MY_TABLE_1] AS vp

INNER JOIN MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE_2 AS k 
ON vp.Code1 = k.Key1 AND vp.Code2 = k.Key3

INNER JOIN MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE_3 AS p 
ON p.Key3 = vp.Code3 

WHERE vp.Year = 2018
GROUP BY
k.Key1, k.Key2, 
p.Key3, p.Key4, 
vp.Key5 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Hmm. I already used GROUP BY and I got 185 results which is not what i want. Hmm, let me think, which columns should group the query by.

Comment: @Vlad - if you add the `COUNT(*)` to your select list, you'll see that there'll be some where it's more than just a *pair* of rows that are duplicated. Add all of the COUNTs together, subtract 185 and you should get 219.